# NullPointerException on Opening SSL Socket to socket-io server

Tags: android, ssl, socket.io, android-4.4-kitkat

I'm trying to connect to Socket IO from an android App with help of Gottox SocketIO.
it works fine on android versions lower an 4.4 but always gets me a NullPointerException on V4.4.2!

Connection is established as follows:

```
    SSLContext ssl_context = null;
    try {
        ssl_context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS", "HarmonyJSSE"); 
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException |  KeyManagementException | NoSuchProviderException  e) { //
        Log.e(LOGIDENT,e.getMessage());
    }
_socket = new SocketIO("SOCKETURI");
_socket.connect(new IOCallback() { ... });
```

Here's the StackTrace:

```
12-12 15:41:13.355  21152-21308/com.mynamespace W/System.err﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException
12-12 15:41:13.375  21152-21308/com.mynamespace W/System.err﹕ at com.android.org.conscrypt.SSLSocketWrapper.initTransportLayer(SSLSocketWrapper.java:48)
12-12 15:41:13.380  21152-21308/com.mynamespace W/System.err﹕ at com.android.org.conscrypt.SSLSocketImpl.init(SSLSocketImpl.java:186)
12-12 15:41:13.380  21152-21308/com.mynamespace W/System.err﹕ at com.android.org.conscrypt.SSLSocketImpl.<init>(SSLSocketImpl.java:111)
12-12 15:41:13.385  21152-21308/com.mynamespace W/System.err﹕ at com.android.org.conscrypt.SSLSocketWrapper.<init>(SSLSocketWrapper.java:37)
12-12 15:41:13.390  21152-21308/com.mynamespace W/System.err﹕ at com.android.org.conscrypt.SSLSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(SSLSocketFactoryImpl.java:91)
12-12 15:41:13.400  21152-21308/com.mynamespace W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.Connection.upgradeToTls(Connection.java:999)
12-12 15:41:13.405  21152-21308/com.mynamespace W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:955)
12-12 15:41:13.415  21152-21308/com.mynamespace W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:411)
12-12 15:41:13.430  21152-21308/com.mynamespace W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:343)
12-12 15:41:13.440  21152-21308/com.mynamespace W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:289)
12-12 15:41:13.440  21152-21308/com.mynamespace W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
12-12 15:41:13.440  21152-21308/com.mynamespace W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:296)
12-12 15:41:13.445  21152-21308/com.mynamespace W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:179)
12-12 15:41:13.450  21152-21308/com.mynamespace W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:246)
12-12 15:41:13.455  21152-21308/com.mynamespace W/System.err﹕ at io.socket.IOConnection.handshake(IOConnection.java:317)
12-12 15:41:13.460  21152-21308/com.mynamespace W/System.err﹕ at io.socket.IOConnection.access$600(IOConnection.java:43)
12-12 15:41:13.460  21152-21308/com.mynamespace W/System.err﹕ at io.socket.IOConnection$ConnectThread.run(IOConnection.java:203)
```

Does any one know of this problem or a similar one? Or is it somehow possible to step into com.android.okhttp.Connection.upgradeToTls as I can't find a row 999 in any of the sources that are available online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I was able to work around this was by updating to the latest Java-WebSocket and changing the `WebsocketTransport` implementation from Gottox SocketIO to pass in a new socket instead of using the old `DefaultWebSocketFactory` as per my comment on the [issue](https://github.com/Gottox/socket.io-java-client/issues/60) and provided solution on this [PR](https://github.com/Gottox/socket.io-java-client/issues/103).